# Two edittexts inside a single cardview with a seperator

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I am implementing an application to search the buses and its time in my location i am impressed by the search layout in redbus application . I would like to implement the same in my application . Can anyone help me with the code to implement the layout.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6wPO.gif]

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/noteBodyEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: why you  want nested scroll view in this layout

Comment: You can use simple realtive/linear layout in this..

Answer (score 0):

you can add imageview as separator

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/noteBodyEdit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        />

<ImageView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="your_src"
/>

  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/noteBodyEdit2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"

        />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin for card:

android:layout_margin="8dp"

Hope this helps.